# pandas is exporting previous columns in addition to others

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to export one specific column from a multi-gigabyte CSV with pandas to another CSV file using .to_csv. However, the output contains two columns, instead of one. Here's a sample output:
    `Case_Number
 3      HZ250496
 89     HZ250409
 197    HZ250503
 673    HZ250424
 911    HZ250455
 1108   HZ250447`

where Case_Number is for the column on the right, because Stack Overflow's indenting doesn't work too well. The previous column is the case ID for this crime dataset. I only want Case_Number. My python code I wrote to generate this is:

```
import pandas
import csv
data = pandas.read_csv("Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv", low_memory=False)
case_number = data["Case_Number"]
data.to_csv('Case_Number.csv', columns = ["Case_Number"])
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `usecols` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if want working only with `Case_Number` column and then `index=False` in [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for avoid `index` write to `csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv", 
                   low_memory=False, 
                   usecols=["Case_Number"])
data.to_csv('Case_Number.csv', index=False)
```